# How can I pass the target Index for specific column in Mui Data Grid Pro?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Problem is when I change the order of Mui columns, it change back to original. So I saved the values for specific column(for what I would like to change the order) in Backend. But Now I do not know how to pass target index for specific column. I have not found any paramter to pass for Grid Column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3H0T.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkNk1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you still not figure it out ?